# Return to first slide when passing end of image carousel

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, image, slider

I have this image carousel. Currently the slides run correctly (they are 4) but once the 4 logos are finished, the slider becomes empty.

How can I get it back to the first slide every time to start over? You can view the slider on the homepage: [fintechdistrict.com](http://fintechdistrict.com)

```html
<h6>OUR PARTNERS:</h6>
<?php 
  $incrementalvartwo = 20;
  $args = array(
    'numberposts=1', 
    'communitypartners', 
    'post_type' => 'custom_post_commun', 
    'posts_per_page' => 7, 
    'orderby' => 'rand', 
    'category_name' => 'communitypartners');

  $posts = get_posts($args);
  foreach($posts as $post): ?>
    <?php $incrementalvartwo = $incrementalvartwo + 1; ?>
    <div class="c-homepage-single-com-partner" id="<?php echo $incrementalvartwo; ?>">
      <!--<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>" >-->
      <?php the_post_thumbnail('post-thumbnail', ['style' => 'max-height: 9vw;' ]); ?>
      <!--</a>-->
      <div class="clearfix"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="post-text">
      <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
    </div>
  <?php endforeach; ?>
  <?php wp_reset_postdata();?>
</article>
```

Comment: Please share more context - "this carousel" is pretty generic, as there can be tons of plugins to achieve this. Additionally, please don't use irrelevant tags, as neither PHP nor Wordpress are involved here

Comment: This is probably more related to jQuery or javascript, which is not provided in the example here. It didn't throw any errors on your site so maybe it's just a misconfiguration of the plugin you are using